# Devise authenticate is redirected to sign in page for both GET and POST method for the same URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I am creating an application using devise authenticate with a route like:

```
"/product/register"
```

I need it to do both GET and POST methods from the form. For that I defined in my route:

```
match "/product/register", to: "register#register_page", :via => [:get, :post]
```

And in register_controller.rb:

```
 def register_page
 if request.post?
 # function of post method
 else 
 #  function of get method
 end 
 end
```

In register controller I used:

```
 before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Which causes its redirect to the devise sign-in page for GET and POSTs to the same URL.

I want a solution for single sign_in for the register controller. How do I do it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved my problem by giving on top of the controller

```
 skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:function_name]
```

function_name is the post method function name from routes. by this it get into the function.